# configurable value to Web Reference C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

i am confuse about this problem. I have a app.config and a web reference but my app.config url value thus not affect my web reference or the web reference url not change from uat process to prod process.

here is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="AFM_SA5.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <applicationSettings>
        <AFM_SA5.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="AFM_SA5_WebReference_TxnService" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://10.81.120.33:8181/FEATS/TxnService.asmx</value>
            </setting>
        </AFM_SA5.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

and here is my reference.cs

```
 public TxnService() {
            this.Url = global::AFM_SA5.Properties.Settings.Default.AFM_SA5_WebReference_TxnService;
            if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true)) {
                this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
            }
            else {
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
            }
        }
```

and my settings.settings

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="AFM_SA5.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="AFM_SA5_WebReference_TxnService" Type="(Web Service URL)" Scope="Application">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">http://ph-sliderinsite.wdc.com:8181/FEATS/TxnService.asmx</Value>
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you want to your app.config.value affect the web reference url

value.

You need to note the following bold code should be your current project name.
[image]

After setting it, if you change the value in app.config and open the Setting.settings, you

will get a message box that ask if you need to change the value in Settings.settings.

Finally, click the yes, the value will be changed.